# How to filter data based on a condition, while keeping the rest of the data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset looking at infections.  I want my final dataset to have both people who have infections and did not have infections. But remove those whose infections developed past 1 year.  For example:

| Infection 0 = No 1 = Yes (SSI) | Time to Infection in Days(TTI) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | NA |
| 1 | 24 |
| 1 | 450 |

I am expecting this:

| Infection 0 = No 1 = Yes (SSI) | Time to Infection in Days(TTI) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | NA |
| 1 | 24 |

When I run

```
dt_one_year <- dt %>% filter(TTI %in% 0:365)
```

It removes both row 1 and row 3, when I want it to keep row 1 and 2.  Any ideas how to do this using dplyr?

Remove only if SSI = 1 and TTI > 365.

Comment: Can you include an example of what you expect the output to look like? (You mention rows 0, 1, 2, and 3 but the example input data you've included only has three rows). Note that R doesn't have row 0 - indexing starts at 1.

Comment: Try `dt %>% filter(!(SSI == 1 & TTI > 365))`

Comment: Or try `dt %>% filter(is.na(TTI) | TTI %in% 0:365)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not subset to rows that meet your criteria?

`dt_one_year = subset(dt, dt$SSI == 0 & dt$TTI < 366)`